# angular interceptor code on beforeSend not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interceptor

I am using the following code, and I looking to push the headers first, followed by the request.  Using JQuery, I just add beforeSend, works fine. But i have changed over to AngularJS (which I am loving... mostly) and I get confused about interceptors!

What confuses me, is if i want to send the header first, where do I tell it, where to send the header. Looking at examples, which is not many, relating too 'beforeSend', I have either not understood, or have not seen any that fits my issue.

Code:

```
    App.factory('postCemment', function($q,requestInterceptor, $http) {

        return {
            fnsend: function(sid, author, comment, callback) {
                $http.Provider.interceptors.push(requestInterceptor);
                $http.post("https://api.appery.io/rest/1/db/collections/comments/",
                    {
                        headers: {"Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                        params: {comment_author : author, comment : comment, statement_id : sid}
                    })
                    .success(function(commentres) {
                        callback(commentres);
                    })
            }
        }
     })

    App.factory('requestInterceptor', function() {
        return {
                'request': function(config) {
                    config.headers = {"X-Appery-Database-Id": dbid}
                    console.log(config);
                    return config;
                }
            }
    })

    App.controller('addCommentBox', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, postCemment) {
        $scope.addCommentData = function() {
            postCemment.fnsend($routeParams.id,$scope.aurhor,$scope.comment, function(res) {
                console.log(res);
            })
        }
    })
```

If I try without any type of interceptor, I just get an error that database is not specified, even though I can see it in the headers in the browser dev screen.

I have used $q and defer before, and I do read that is may be required, as some examples do not use it, but this is where the confusion is.  Even with a defer, at what point do I defer?

Thanks in advance.

Andrew

Comment: Did you push `'requestInterceptor'` in the `$httpProvider.interceptors` array in a config function ?

Comment: Where is `dbid` coming from ?

Comment: @lib3d I pushed the service in the 'postComment' service, `$http.Provider.interceptors.push(requestInterceptor);`  Not in the requestInterceptor service.  Is that what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem  dbid is just a number and is a global var.  In the headers I can see the number, using browser dev tools, as I explained.

Comment: @AndrewWalker If `$http.Provider` is a reference to the `$httpProvider`, that should work with either `$http.Provider.interceptors.push(requestInterceptor);` or `$http.Provider.interceptors.push('requestInterceptor');`. Without this external reference to the provider, you should use the normal way : `App.config(function($httpProvider) { $httpProvider.interceptors.push('requestInterceptor'); });`

Comment: @lib3d Thank you for your help:)   I have changed it too `$httpProvider` but it comes back with an error.  In the Factory service, do I need to call `$httpProivder` as this seems to be the error ?

Comment: If i add $httpProvider, i get an error that its not defined. Looking at the example on Angular, I am unsure where to put mine request where it is recognised ?

Comment: In the factory, you are not in a config phase. In the factory you can injector `$http` without access to the provider. In the config phase, you can inject the provider `$httpProvider` and push the interceptor name with a string `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('requestInterceptor')`